# Using JSON to put objects into a recyclerview

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to use JSON to insert images into a recycler view. It seems like the information is being read, but it never stops and eventually gives me an out of memory exception. The trace says Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed over and over for about 2 minutes then throws the error. The real error here isn't clear to me or I would give more information, please ask questions for clarification if you need it.

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        JsonAnimalApi jsonAnimalApi = retrofit.create(JsonAnimalApi.class);
        Call<Animal> call = jsonAnimalApi.getAnimals();
        System.out.println("Here");
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Animal>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Animal> call, Response<Animal> response) {
                System.out.println("HERE");
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    while (names.size() < 50) names.add(response.body().getPicture());
                    tvResponse.setText("Code: " + response.code());
                    return;
                }
RecyclerView recyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        RecyclerViewAdapter rAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(names, this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(rAdapter);
```

```
public interface JsonAnimalApi {
    @GET("animals")
    Call<Animal> getAnimals();
}
```

```
public class Animal {
    private ImageView  picture;
    private String status;
    private String message;

    public ImageView getPicture() {
        return picture;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<ImageView> mAnimalNames;
    private OnNoteListener mOnNote;
    public RecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<ImageView> mAnimalNames, OnNoteListener mOnNote) {
        this.mAnimalNames = mAnimalNames;
        this.mOnNote = mOnNote;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_listitem, parent, false);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view, mOnNote);
        return holder;
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: ");
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mAnimalNames.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        ImageView animalName;
        OnNoteListener onNote;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, OnNoteListener onNote) {
            super(itemView);
            animalName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.animal_name);
            this.onNote = onNote;

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mOnNote.onNoteClick(getAdapterPosition(), mAnimalNames);
        }
    }

    public interface OnNoteListener {
        void onNoteClick(int pos, ArrayList<ImageView> names);
    }
}
```

Comment: share some code where how you attach adapter into recyclerview

Comment: I have done as you asked, under the JSON call.

Comment: oh my god I thought that was a fake API URL, that is the best API I've ever seen

Comment: add your json data.

Comment: The JSON data looks something like this (according to the API site) : {
    "message": "https://images.dog.ceo/breeds/hound-english/n02089973_255.jpg",
    "status": "success"
}

Answer (score 1):

A couple problems I see: it looks like you're trying to use Gson to fill in an `ImageView` directly:

```java
public class Animal {
    private ImageView  picture;
```

This isn't going to work, because whatever format the `picture` attribute is in is not compatible with `ImageView`'s internal implementation (and that internal implementation could change without warning).

But you've got a more fundamental issue in your `onResponse` - your conditional is reversed:

```
if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
```

You're only adding the items if the response is *not* successful, rather than if it is.

Beyond that, depending on the rest of your code, you may need to use one of the `notify...` methods on your adapter to inform the RecyclerView about the new items.

Comment: Wow thank you, can't believe I didn't notice that. I fixed the conditional, but now I've figured out by adding tags that the code doesn't execute that far even. It only gets to Call<Animal> call = jsonAnimalApi.getAnimals().

Comment: Hmmmm....like the "Here" doesn't print?  The code _looks_ correct to me...you're able to see similar log statements print before it?

Comment: Exactly. I put the "Here" in several locations above and it prints out, but after that statement it doesn't.

Comment: and it's not crashing or anything?  There aren't any exceptions in the logcat?

Comment: It will throw an OutOfMemory exception after a few minutes of being suspended and crash, but no others.

Comment: It's a bit hard to debug that sort of thing without the full picture, but I'd point you to https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler - it should help you figure out what exactly is allocating so much memory.  My guess is something is stuck in an infinite loop somewhere, and that that's probably also causing your other problems.

Answer (score 0):

**For some reason you include an `imageView` in your Animal class, so remove it:**

```
public class Animal {

private String status;
private String message;



public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}
 }
```

**The `while` loop**

```
 //names must be of type string

while (names.size() < 50) names.add(response.body().getMessage());
```

**And `mAnimalNames` in the adapter must of type String**

```
private ArrayList<String> mAnimalNames;

//constructor
public RecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<String> mAnimalNames,..........
```

**Also not sure why use a while loop, maybe trying to fill the list:**

Do this:

```
 @Override
public void onResponse(Call<Animal> call, Response<Animal> response) {

if(response.isSuccessful()){
for(int i=0 ; i<50 ; i++){
//names has to be of type String
names.add(response.body().getMessage())
}
RecyclerView recyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
RecyclerViewAdapter rAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(names, this);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
recyclerView.setAdapter(rAdapter);
}
```

Comment: I want it to put pictures into the recycler view though, can I still do this?

Comment: `imageView` is not a data you add from JSON, what I did for you above helps you pass the urls to the adapter as a string, then in the adapter you use the strings to display images in an `imageview` that is part of the recyclerview item.

Comment: the urls in the json are what you want to use to display images in the adpater.